# Ajuda com Wampserver! Helpme! Não está ficando verde!

Tags: apache, wamp, openssl

Pessoal alguém me ajuda com uma coisinha no `WampServer`.

Eu segui esse tutorial do YT (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2KmzkPWty7Y&t=522s)
O Apache no vídeo é versão 2.4.4 e o meu é versão 2.4.23
Eu segui todos os passos até a parte onde ele ativa o `ssl_module` e daí reinicia.
No vídeo o `WampServer` fica verde...
No meu continua laranja...

Alguém sabe me dizer o por que disso?

Comment: Algum detalhe do log? Ajudaria, provavelmente deve ser algum problema com portas já usadas. Me diz se você tem skype no computaor e que porta escolheu

Comment: Não mano. O problema não tá nas portas, eu uso skype normalmente e wamp normalmente... Antes funcionava, só na hora que eu abro o `ssl_module` aí buga.